# Create basic (Eclipse-style) Android project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to follow tutorials on Android but the default project that Android Studio creates has stuff like PlaceholderFragment and fragment XML files.

I'm having trouble following any of these guides because they all expect you to use Eclipse, which creates a different standard project without all this fragment code.

Should I just switch to Eclipse?

Comment: You could also try to use IntellJ IDEA instead of Android Studio. It is very similar to Android Studio, but it still uses the standard build and project structure (similar to Eclipse) and is very stable for day-to-day use. I went this route before Android Studio was available due to my personal dislike of Eclipse and successfully created various apps/games using it. As a bonus, it will get you familiar with using Android Studio. However, if you have no real issues using Eclipse it would definitely be easier use while following tutorials made with it in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend synchronizing your tutorials and tools. Right now, that probably means switching to Eclipse. Android Studio is still an early-access previews. [I don't recommend that newcomers to Android start with Android Studio](http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/05/16/android-studio-early-access-preview-and-you.html), in part because of the struggles that you are encountering. Android Studio uses project structures set up for the new Gradle-based build system, which is different from what Eclipse uses. Plus, the wizards may generate different files, as you are seeing.

Now, if you can find a set of tutorials that happen to be based on Android Studio, and you want to go that route, that's your call. But a newcomer to Android trying to translate instructions for Eclipse into instructions for Android Studio is likely to get frustrated. So, if your tutorials are for Eclipse, I would recommend using Eclipse.